# Cannot use jQuery in Laravel Blade file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I am trying to define my page specific Javascript in my blade file by defining a separate section for it in the file.  I can add the same jQuery code in the app.js file and it works without issue, but when I put it in the blade file I get an error of

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Layout file - app.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="fixed-nav sticky-footer bg-dark" id="page-top">
    <!-- Navigation-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav">
        <!-- Nav Stuff -->
    </nav>
    <!--  End Navigation -->
    <!--  Body  -->
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
        <footer class="sticky-footer">
            <!-- footer stuff -->
        </footer>
    </div>
    @yield('script')
</body>
</html>
```

Content Page - page1.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <!--  Page Stuff -->            
</div>
@endsection

@section('script')
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        alert('hello world');
    });
</script>
@endsection
```

I would prefer not to put all of my Javascript in the single app.js file, I would like to be able to use this section fine.  Straight Javascript works fine here, but the jQuery does not.

edit:

Here is the app.js file that includes the jQuery library.

```
require('jquery');
require('./bootstrap');
require('jquery-easing');

//  Administration Controller - Add System Type -> This code works just fine.
var numSysDataRows = 5;
$('#add-customer-information').click(function()
{
    $('#system-customer-information').append('<div class="form-group"><label for="col'+numSysDataRows+'">System Data:</label><input type="text" name="col[]" id="col'+numSysDataRows+'" class="form-control" /></div>');
    numSysDataRows++;
});
```

If I look at the source code and check the app.js file from the web server, I do see that jQuery is loaded into the app.js file.

Comment: So where in the code the **jquery** source  is included?

Comment: Seem there is no load jquery.js in your blade

Comment: Jquery is loaded into my app.js file. Do I need to load it a second time in the main page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Laravel loads jQuery by default, so it will be there unless you removed it from your complied app.js (running an npm commands to compile from your assets). The issue is that you are deferring this script. jQuery is being loaded after the page JavaScript is run.

Try removing the `defer` command.

If that doesn't work, see if jQuery is in your app.js file. If not, use a cdn or copy it to your public folder.

Comment: I have edited the question to show the app.js file.  It is loading jQuery (and yes I did compile it).  Where is the "defer" command?

Comment: Remove it from: `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove "defer" from `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>`.

Paste jquery script tags below app.js then,

1. install npm
2. remove vue template in resouces/js/app.js
3. type "npm run dev" and hit enter
4. repeat #3 2 times

Then no `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` will appear

[NPM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoPZV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I added jquery script tags
[Jquery script tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXLpu.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that in the case that you are using the jquery CDN, you can try to put it in your head tag, I had that same problem and I have been able to solve it this way

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I don't see you add file bootstrap and jquery. Have you added jQuery and Bootstrap file yet? 
If not you can see in here : [jquery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp) [Bootstap](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_get_started.asp)